# Nginx config doesn't work for a specific domain

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a domain called behnia.com, also behnia**.ir**  ("behnia" is example and not real).

My Nginx .conf file for both of the domains is the same, except that I've changed server_names & certificates for each of the domains.

The problem is, the config is working beautifully for behnia.com; but It's not for **behnia.ir**.

---

What is shown in **behnia.ir**:

[image: Seems it doesn't catch my frontend service]

---

My Nginx config file for **behnia.com**:

```
server {
        client_max_body_size 1000m;
        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name behnia.com;

        location /static {
                alias /var/www/behnia-website/staticfiles;
        }

        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

        location /fa {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }


        location /en {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

        location /admin {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

        location /media {
                alias /var/www/behnia-website/mediafiles;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:30301;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

        ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/website/deployment-configs/behnia.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/website/deployment-configs/behnia.com/privkey.pem;

}


server {
    if ($host = behnia.com) {
        return 301 https://$host:443$request_uri;
    }
        listen 80; listen [::]:80;

        server_name behnia.com;
        return 404;
}


server {
    if ($host = www.behnia.com) {
        return 301 https://behnia.com:443$request_uri;
    }
        
        listen 80; listen [::]:80;
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/website/deployment-configs/www.behnia.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/website/deployment-configs/www.behnia.com/privkey.pem;
        
        server_name www.behnia.com;
        return 404;
}
```

And my **behnia.ir** config file:

```
server {
        client_max_body_size 1000m;
        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name behnia.ir;

        location /static {
                alias /var/www/behnia-website/staticfiles;
        }

        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

        location /fa {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }


        location /en {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

        location /admin {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

        location /media {
                alias /var/www/behnia-website/mediafiles;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:30301;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

        ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/website/deployment-configs/behnia.ir/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/website/deployment-configs/behnia.ir/privkey.pem;

}



server {
    if ($host = behnia.ir) {
        return 301 https://behnia.ir:443$request_uri;
    }
        
        listen 80; listen [::]:80;

        server_name behnia.ir;
        return 404;
}

server {
    if ($host = www.behnia.ir) {
        return 301 https://behnia.ir:443$request_uri;
    }
        
        listen 80; listen [::]:80;
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/website/deployment-configs/www.behnia.ir/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/website/deployment-configs/www.behnia.ir/privkey.pem;
        
        server_name www.behnia.ir;
        return 404;
}
```

---

I expect **behnia.ir** to be shown just like behnia.com, and I need it to be separate.

Also, I tried removing the .com config and so Nginx was using only behnia.ir config, but the result was the same.

---

**[Update 27-Aug-2023]**

I'm 99% sure, & I somehow figured out what the problem is, but it is still very confusing for me: The problem was because the IP of my server is banned(and I knew it before); So to bypass the ban, I tried to use Cloudflare CDN. So now, my website shows its content very well(also Django backend). BUT ONLY FOR the ".com" DOMAIN! And the picture that I uploaded above is the result of accessing the behnia.ir domain! I still don't know what's going on; I read the Nginx logs & I know that Nginx catches the requests, but why doesn't it use my configs?! This is what I want to know now :)) @

Comment: Config is looking fine to me. Are you sure the configuration file gets loaded at all?

Comment: I'm 100% sure, & I somehow figured out what the problem is, but it is still very confusing for me: The problem was because the IP of my server is banned(and I knew it before); So to bypass the ban, I tried to use Cloudflare CDN. So now, my website shows its content very well(also Django backend). BUT ONLY FOR the ".com" DOMAIN! And the picture that I uploaded above is the result of accessing the behnia.ir domain! I still don't know what's going on; I read the Nginx logs & I know that Nginx catches the requests, but why doesn't it use my configs?! This is what I want to know now :)) @Geilmaker

Comment: Can you share your nginx logs when accessing behnia.ir?